# HTML/Javascript/CSS Collapsible Menu not staying closed when refreshed

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

as it states in the title, my collapsible menu is not staying closed when the page is refreshed. Every time the page is loaded, the collapsible menu is fully expanded out, even if before the refresh it was completely closed. This is a bit of a problem, because there is a lot of stuff in this collapsible.

Here is basic code for it:

CSS:

```
//some code here for the design, background color and stuff that shouldn't matter,
// .active is what I think I need

.active, .collapsible:hover{
background-color: #02538D;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="collapsible">Tutorials</button>
<div>
    <div class="content">
    <p>
      <?php
         //some php here for output of collapsible
      ?>
    </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
    <p>
       <?php>
         //some php here for output of collapsible
       ?>
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for(i = 0; i< coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
         this.classList.toggle("active");
         var content = this.nextElementSibling;
         if(content.style.display === "block") {
               content.style.display = "none";
         }
         else {
               content.style.display = "block";
         }
     });
}
</script>
```

I'm a beginner when it comes to JavaScript so I'm pretty sure that's where the error is but any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you've provided, the state of the menu is never saved - so when the page is refreshed everything is simply 'reset' to the default.

One solution is of course to use 'display:none;' as the default in your css. That would make the menu hidden on page-refresh but the problem would persist if you need it to also ***stay visible*** between refreshes if the users have opened it.

In that case you could set a cookie with javascript at the time you toggle the styles:

**HTML**

```
<button class="collapsible">Collapsible 1</button>
<div>
    <div class="menu-item">
    <p>Content 1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-item">
    <p>Content 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");

for(i = 0; i< coll.length; i++) {
    var cookies = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie).split(";");
    for(i=0;i<cookies.length;i++) {
      if(cookies[i] == "menu-state=hide") {
                var content = coll[i].nextElementSibling;
        content.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
         var content = this.nextElementSibling;
         if(content.style.display === "block") {
               content.style.display = "none";
               document.cookie = "menu-state=hide";
         }
         else {
               content.style.display = "block";
               document.cookie = "menu-state=display";
         }
     });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hxcy1vLr/41/

The above code will check if there is a cookie with the name and value "menu-state=hide". If there is, the menu will be hidden initially. This cookie is set and changed when you click the toggle.

About cookies in javascript:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Colleen - Awesome! Wish you the best of luck with all your projects! :-D